# Can't display log anywhere in railo

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, railo, cfml

I want to display log in standard browser console in `Railo`.

This is my code :

```
log.info("Event Handler Called");
```

or

```
WriteLog (text="Event Handler Is Called", type="error", application=true, file="", log="");


The text "Event Handler Is Called" is not logged anywhere.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your info is being written to file. To display your info on the browser you would have to output it just as you normally do any other content. For example:

```
<cfscript>
      msg = "Event Handler Is Called";
      WriteOutput( msg );
      WriteLog (text=msg, type="error", application=true, file="", log="");
</cfscript>
```

The above code will both output `msg` to the browser and to the `{railo-install-dir}/WEB-INF/railo/logs/exception.log` log file.

**NOTE**: `WriteLog()` (or `cflog`) is a server-side tag that does not interact directly with browser (client). We normally use `JavaScript` to interact with the browser.

Comment: i am new in coldfusion and i want to show log on my browse console i not now how to do that? if any one known that then pls help me..